# What is the best way to display non entity data in asp MVC View

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a non-entity custom and raw SQL query in asp MVC controller with c#. I want to send this data to the asp MVC razor view and display them in a tabular format with their corresponding column headers. How can I get the header (the custom query can involve any number of tables) and display the data in a tabular format? I am grateful for the help.

```
public class QueryScriptController : Controller
    {

        private EntitiesContext db = new EntitiesContext();



        public ActionResult CreateQueryScript(string SqlQueryString )
        {


          try
                {

                    var ResultList= db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(SqlQueryString).ToList();
                    return   View(ResultList);
                }

                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,pass the data to a Viewbag like shown below and pass that Viewbag to the razor view.

```
    public class QueryScriptController : Controller
    {

        private EntitiesContext db = new EntitiesContext();



        public ActionResult CreateQueryScript(string SqlQueryString )
        {


          try
                {

                    var ResultList= db.Database.SqlQuery<string> 
                    (SqlQueryString).ToList();
                  ViewBag.data =ResultList;
                    return   View();
                }

                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }

        }

}
```

In your razor page,call the Viewbag like shown below and call the data objects you get from the query.

```
@{
    var data = ViewBag.data;
}
using somemodel;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>PaySlip</title>
</head>
<body >
   <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h5 align="center" style="text-decoration: underline;">Results</h5>
                        <table className="table-bordered table-striped">

                            <thead>

                            <tr>

                                <th style="width: 60%">Column 1</th>
                                <th style="width: 30%">Column 2</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in @data)
                            {
                                <tr >

                                    <td style="width: 60%">@item.object1</td>
                                    <td style="width: 30%">@item.object2</td>

                                </tr>
                            }

                            </tbody>


                        </table>
                    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a non-entity type query, I don't know the column names and the corresponding objects in advance (raw query)

Comment: How come you don't know the data you are working with but you want to show it?Debug it and see the results you are getting and show the columns

Comment: as the question states, the raw query could join any number of tables from database